# No mouse responce on html audio (windows app ionic)

Tags: html, windows, audio, ionic-framework

I build an app for android and windows (universal app) but i can't figure out why the audio doesn't work for windows app, it work perfectly on browser and android.

```
<audio controls="true">
  <source src="/www/audio/FRCath.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

With the code above i got the player but nothing happen if i hit the play button. The player display the correct duration of the file, so the path must be good.
And this code work perfectly on edge.

edit: it work when i use my keyboard but the player doesn't respond to the mouse.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="audio">
  <ion-content sroll="false">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="/www/audio/FRCath.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://www.scricciolo.com/eurosongs/Phylloscopus.inornatus.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...you can remove the true attribute from the audio tag. And i don't know whether i am correct or not but i think your sound file is wrong somewhere, that's why i have used a different sound file.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.scricciolo.com/eurosongs/Phylloscopus.inornatus.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: I've discovered that the player work with the keyboard, the issue is more likely to be with the mouse or z-index. But even with really simple code it doesn't work.